# Understanding Cartesian product in naive set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read this definition in Analysis by Zorich.

[image]

I am confused with this.

For example, let $X=\{1,2\},Y=\{a,b\}$.

Then $\mathcal P(X)\bigcup\mathcal P(Y)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

But $(1,a):=\{\{1\},\{1,a\}\}$ is not a subset of $\mathcal P(X)\bigcup\mathcal P(Y)$ since $\{1,a\}$ is not in $\mathcal P(X)\bigcup\mathcal P(Y)$.

How should I understand this?

Any help will be appreciated.

---

It seems to be a typo. Please check the answer below:)

Comment: Note $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X)\cup\mathcal P(Y))$, and not $\mathcal P(X)\cup\mathcal P(Y)$.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: He said "not a subset", so he knows.

Comment: Did you roll a die to decide the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. There is a mistake, which of course points to the unnaturalness of set theory even though it is well capable of capturing standard concepts such as ordered pairs and cartesian products.

Using the Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs, we can define:
$
\def\pow{\mathcal{P}}
$

> $X \times Y \overset{Δ}= \{ z : z \in \pow(\pow(X \cup Y)) \land \exists x,y\ ( x \in X \land y \in Y \land (x,y) = z ) \}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very clear of your point. Could you please point out my mistake and explain this definition more explicitly? Thanks:)

Comment: @gžd15: My point is that your textbook is wrong. $\pow(X) \cup \pow(Y)$ is almost always a strict subset of $\pow(X \cup Y)$. The former takes subsets of $X$ and of $Y$ separately before collecting them together. The latter collects the elements of $X$ and $Y$ first before taking subsets.

Comment: @gžd15: As for why the definition I gave works, we take $X \cup Y$ to make sure we get all elements in either $X$ or $Y$, then we take subsets so that we get all (unordered) pairs of these elements in $X \cup Y$, then we take the collection of all sets of these pairs because an ordered pair (under Kuratowski's definition) is a set containing either one or two of these pairs.

Comment: Hmm... Now I'm clear. Your answer really helps. Thank you again:)

Comment: @gžd15: By the way this definition is not at all the natural one in naive set theory. It is done in this way precisely so that the specification axiom of ZF permits its construction. In truly naive set theory one would just write "$\{ z : \exists x,y\ ( x \in X \land y \in Y \land (x,y) = z ) \}$" using unrestricted comprehension, but of course this is useless because naive set theory is inconsistent.

Comment: @user21820, could you please explain what you mean by the inconsistency of naive set theory? Btw, I also can't understand why in naive set theory the set above is given as for some $x \in X$ and for some $y \in Y$ instead of "for all". I will really appreciate and be grateful to you if you explain this.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov: Unrestricted comprehension in naive set theory allows you to construct $R = \{ x : x \notin x \}$. Now, is "$R \in R$" true or false? I am not sure what your second question is about. I stated in my comment what we intuitively want, but it is not allowed by ZFC, so we need to add the "$z \in \pow(\pow(X \cup Y))$" part, and this has nothing to do with the "$\exists x,y$" part. As for why not "forall", you are going to have to think carefully about what the set membership means: $z \in X \times Y$ iff $z$ is a pair $(x,y)$ for **some** $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.